# To send Chat Invitation, to GTalk using Google App Engine(Python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How can i send Chat invitation over GTalk using Google App Engine(Python), i was searching for code in documentation of GAE, but i didnt get it. As i am new to Python, please post me the code too...

Comment: And since you've probably had a long day thinking about all the cool stuff you can do with "your" new code, would you like a massage? In the real world we're happy to offer advice when you've given it a shot, maybe tried a few things. Asking for free handouts meaning "I didn't do any work, you do it for me!" from people is not only likely to get you zero responses, but it's just plain rude. Looking at some of your previous questions it looks like you should really spend some time with the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: yeah! right i should have tried it out...and explored the GAE Documentation... actually suddenly they put me to do this task..and i was just lost...and i dont know Python too.. any way i will not repeat this... thank u @Wayne Werner...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/overview.html

```
from google.appengine.api import xmpp
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class FooHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        xmpp.send_invite('example@gmail.com')

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('.*', FooHandler)], debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, @Drew Sears... for helping...